# PHP - Creating categories and tags using the woocommerce REST api(V3) issue

Tags: php, rest, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce plugin version 2.4.7 and want to populate my woo store using the woocommerce REST api(i'm using V3 of the api)

Below is the php code:

```
   print_r( $client->products->create( array( 'title' => 'product_name','sku' => 'sku_value', 'type' => 'simple', 'regular_price' => '1000', 'short_description'=>'short description', 'categories' => Array ('category1','category2','category3' ), 'tags'=> array('product_tag'))));
```

The product is created but two properties are not created i.e **categories** and **tags**

```
["categories"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
["tags"]=>
   array(0) {
    }
```

as shown above, categories and tags are not created(returns an empty array) in the api call but ALL the other properties are created.

I should mention that this happened once i upgraded my woocommerce plugin. my previous version was V2.3 and while using this everything was working well. Immediately after upgrading my plugin, the categories and tags properties ceased being created when creating a product.

I'm stuck on this and do not really know why this is happening so any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 and 3 of WooCommerce REST API use the following code to create categories

```
// Product categories
if ( isset( $data['categories'] ) && is_array( $data['categories'] ) ) {
    $term_ids = array_unique( array_map( 'intval', $data['categories'] ) );
    wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $term_ids, 'product_cat' );
}
```

As can be seen that the code "expects" an array of integers and not string terms. You'll need to change the data structure you are passing to the API, change `('category1','category2','category3' ),` to their respective ID's and the code will work. Do the same for tags as well.

```
'categories' => Array('category1','category2','category3' ),  
// replace category1, category2 etc with the relevant integer ID's
```

Comment: Hey Anand. I am not using existing categories, rather i am creating a category for each product being created. so when i say 'category1', this is a category i'm creating using the api call. as mentioned, this was working perfectly before i updated the woocommerce plugin to the latest version

Comment: Yes, things have changed in the newer API. This will now be a 2 step process, first create the categories and then pass the integer ids of those categories when creating the product. Have a look at the [documentation](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#products-properties) , it states :  _In write-mode need to pass a array of categories IDs (integer)_

Comment: hmm..seems quite inefficient..what happens when say forexample i want to populate my store with products from the database using the api. i loop through the products and populate them to my store. doesn't this mean i have to assign categories later since i cannot create them when i'm creating the product.that would be quite tedious incase i have multiple products!

Comment: The code defines an action hook after the product created and passes you the id of the product and the data that was sent to the api. You can make use of that hook and create your categories as required and attach it to the product.